# Maximum number of minimal set of generators of groups of order $n$

Tags: group-theory, supremum-and-infimum

I was discussing with my friend this curious problem: Consider the number of generating elements for groups with order $n$. We define $R_n$ as follows:

$$
R_n = \{k \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \mid\exists\text{ a group $G$ of order $n$ such that $G$ is generated by $k$ elements minimally}\} 
$$

Here, I define "generated by $k$ elements minimally" as in the minimal number of elements required to generate $G$.

It is obvious that $\inf{R_n} = 1$ always, as we can take the cyclic group. What about $\sup R_n$? What is the behaviour of the $\sup R_n$ as $n \to \infty$? Perhaps there is a "nice" function $f$ such that $\frac{\sup{R_n}}{f(n)} \to c$ for some constant $c$?

Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: Why is $$\sup R_n\neq n?$$ I ask because the set of all elements of a group is a generating set.

Comment: I would like the elements to be generated minimally. I'm pretty sure that for sufficiently large $n$, taking away one (appropriate) element from the whole group will still generate the whole group, so it should be that $\sup R_n \leq n - 1$.

Comment: Yes, and that element is the identity. I'm sorry I overlooked that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smallest order for finite group that needs many elements to generate it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78179/smallest-order-for-finite-group-that-needs-many-elements-to-generate-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It tends to infinity: $\sup R_n\rightarrow\infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

One way of seeing this is to consider direct products. For a group $G$, write $d(G)$ for the minimum number of generators needed to generate $G$, and write $G^
k$ for the direct product of $k$ copies of $G$. The following is a theorem of Weigold*, but is very close to a result of Dey**.

**Theorem 2.1.** For every non-trivial finite group $G$ and every positive integer $k$, $d(G^k) > \log_{|G|}k$.

So we have that $R_{|G|^k}\geq d(G^k) > \log_{|G|}k$. As $\log_{|G|}k\rightarrow\infty$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$, the result follows.

*Theorem 2.1 of Wiegold, James. "Growth sequences of finite groups." Journal of the Australian Mathematical Society 17, no. 2 (1974): 133-141. [link](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S1446788700016712)

**Dey, I. M. S. "Embeddings in Non‐Hopf Groups." Journal of the London Mathematical Society 2, no. 1 (1969): 745-749.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I realise I forgot to include this in my question, but I'm also interested in how the $\limsup R_n$ behaves as $n \to \infty$ (e.g. perhaps $\lim \frac{\sup R_n}{n} = c$ for some constant $c$. By any chance is there a theorem that addresses this problem?

Comment: @ClementYung I'm not sure. However, the paper of Weigold is the first in a series of 5 papers (Growth sequences of finite groups I-V) where he considers the behaviour of $d(G^k)$. As $R_{|G|^k}\geq d(G^k)$, these papers are very relevant to what you are after.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**  $(\mathbb Z/ p \mathbb Z)^n$ is a vector space of dimension $n$ over  $(\mathbb Z/ p \mathbb Z)$. Therefore, it needs at least $n$ generators.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to show that a group of order $n$ can be generated with $\lfloor \log_2(n)\rfloor$ elements. (This follows from Lagrange's Theorem.) The groups $C_2^m$ show that this bound is tight. This question has been asked many times on this site, and the answer is easy to find by googling.